# Fetching POST Data inside Paypal Smart Button Block not working on Mobile/iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, paypal

I´m quite new into Webdevelopment, but I got some strange behaviour when Fetching a POST Request between Webinterfaces on Windows and on Mobile Device (Iphone 14.4.2) in combination with Paypal´s Smart Payment Buttons!

My goal is to gather some data from a Page and to POST it to my server in order to process it.
Furthermore there is also a redirect to another page inside my code.

My simple POST Route with Express on Node.js:

```
app.post('/paypalSuccess', async (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

My Redirect and postData Functions:

```
        function Redirect() {
            window.location = "https://www.example.com/success";
        }
        
        async function postData(url, data){
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST', 
                mode: 'cors', 
                cache: 'no-cache', 
                credentials: 'same-origin', 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                redirect: 'follow',
                referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });
            return response.json();
        }
```

And here comes the Paypal block:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MyClientID&currency=EUR"></script>
<script>

let description = 'Some Long Description String with special some pipes | as special Character';
let text = 'A short Description';

        paypal.Buttons({
            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {

                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '<%= fullPrice %>'
                        },
                        description: text,
                    }]
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: async function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    description += `|| PayPal Kauf ID: ${details.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id} || E-Mail: ${details.payer.email_address} Name: ${details.payer.name.given_name}`
                    postData('https://www.example.com/paypalSuccess', description)
                    Redirect();
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

When the Order is successful and i did it on Windows, then I get the expected result in my console:

> { '"Some Long Description String with special some pipes | as special Character PayPal Kauf ID: 4P533916UA615042F || E-Mail: sb-1o1745807834@personal.example.com Name: John"': '' }

I know it´s not quite the purpose to use an JSON Object like this, but so far I´m happy with that ;)
And it redirects shortly after that to https://www.example.com/success

Now comes the strange part, when i do the same via my Iphone, then it doesn´t hit the POST Route.
But the Payment itself was successful and it still redirects to /success which shows me that onApprove is somehow still executed..

Thus I moved the postData command outside of the paypal Block for test purposes:

```
postData('https://www.example.com/paypalSuccess', 'test')
```

And now when accessing the site with my mobile i get an output on my console:

> { '"test"': '' }

But unluckily this "solution" will not help me!

So for me it looks like Paypal "messes around" with it, maybe because it opens a new site?
(But even when i force Paypal to open a new Tab on my PC it still works there..)

P.S. I have the same behaviour with xmlHTTPRequest.
P.P.S. I had not the possibilty to check this behaviour with Android yet.

Thank you &
Kind regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should never do a capture and then post data from the client side, much less a capture and a post followed by a redirect. This is a bad design.

Instead, make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with a Smart Button approval flow that calls them as needed: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server